# How can I switch virtualenv from reticulate in R?

Tags: r, virtualenv, reticulate

In R package reticulate there is a function use_virtualenv but it does not look like I can call it twice with different virtualenvs, second call is always ignored.

Is there a way to deactivate first virtualenv so I can call `use_virtualenv("venv2")` with the expected behavior?

```
#initialize
require(reticulate)
virtualenv_create("venv1")
virtualenv_create("venv2")

#call first virtualenv
use_virtualenv("venv1") 
py_config() #show venv1 specs

#call second vrtualenv
use_virtualenv("venv2")
py_config() # still show venv1 specs, I want venv2 here
```

I think `unloadNamespace("reticulate")` could work but in my case first call is made by another package...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In short: By restarting the R session! You can't switch virtualenv in `reticulate` once chosen!

I tried it (but chose `"venv2"` first).

```
> use_python("venv1", T)
Error in use_python("venv1", T) : 
  Specified version of python 'venv1' does not exist.
> use_python("~/.virtualenvs/venv1", T)
ERROR: The requested version of Python ('~/.virtualenvs/venv1') cannot
be used, as another version of Python
('/home/josephus/.virtualenvs/venv2/bin/python') has already been
initialized. Please restart the R session if you need to attach
reticulate to a different version of Python.
Error in use_python("~/.virtualenvs/venv1", T) : 
  failed to initialize requested version of Python
```

So reticulate messages, that one has to start a new session to choose new virtual environment.
This must apply to `use_virtualenv(<xxx>, T)` too, though it is not as verbose as `use_python(<xxx>, T)`.

Comment: thanks didn't notice this but yeah figured out I need to unload reticulate (or restart R). Was hoping for an easier soluion. I might open an issue on reticulate.

Comment: @BenoitLondon Yes, they should change it ... for what one has virtualenvironments - for easy switching...